# Attaching script file to web site

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have next question: can I in any way attach my script file to a web site opened in my web browser? This script should be executed only in my machine and should emulate events like `onclick` ,`onmouseover`, etc. I found that I can emulate that events in this way:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element_id');
var o = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
o.initMouseEvent( 'click', true, true, window, 1, 12, 345, 7, 220, false, false, true, false, 0, null );
element.dispatchEvent(o);
```

But I don't understand how I can implement this code in concrete my situation? Where should I locate this code? How do I attach it the site? How can I generate browser's events for this site? And can I do it?

Comment: Have a look at userscripts and bookmarks with `javascript:` urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bookmark the script in your browser and then click the bookmark to run it on the page you are currently on.

[Load external JS from bookmarklet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106425/load-external-js-from-bookmarklet)