# Running a JavaScript script in all browsers installed on an operating system from one place

Tags: javascript, linux, operating-system, cross-browser, restriction

I have a JavaScript script that blocks a group of 1 or more websites I don't wish to visit like **news websites** that I have an addiction-like behavior to.

It is a hassle for me to run it in three different environments: Firefox (Greasemonkey), Chrome (Tampermonkey), Edge (Tampermonkey).

Is there a more aesthetic way to on it for all browsers "brutally" (without specifically allow it in a given browser)?
<sub>As I use Windows10 mostly maybe an AutoHotkey solution be helpful but I do care about Linux users (which I'm one of them).</sub>

Comment: You might block the IPs completely via the hosts file

Comment: Used strange feature yesterday, maybe it can help you 2 - started by need to attach ansi_up from github https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106425/load-external-js-from-bookmarklet/57921981#57921981 Let me know if it works for you eventually to know it can be used as a general portable helper or not.

Comment: @CertainPerformance some sites have sub sites with sub domains which I do need to access so I believe it's not good for me... Thank you,

Comment: @Tom thanks but I totally misunderstands your comment: how could this run globally for all browsers for one place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a Proxy-Server to restrict the user to go to specific Websites:
It works for Windows, Linux  and Mac and is Browser independent.

In addition Javascript could be disabled in the Browser and your Script takes no effect.